# CSS works in Firefox but not Chrome. How can I fix it?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, flexbox

Below is a simple HTML page that renders very differently in Chrome and Firefox. It looks like Chrome has a bug. I tried hard but could not find a workaround to make it work in Chrome. My best attempt was wrapping the `img` in a `div` with a `height`, but it does not work nicely when the size of the picture is limited by the width of the browser. Could you suggest a workaround to make it work in Chrome?

To clarify: in Chrome, if I make the browser window very wide, the picture will take the full width, and become taller than the screen. In Firefox, the paragraph below the picture remains visible, which is what I want to obtain. How can I make it work in Chrome?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>CSS Magic</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
</head>

<body>
  <div style="display:flex;flex-direction:column;max-height:100vh">
    <h1>Title of the page that works in Firefox but not Chrome</h1>
    <img alt="goban" style="margin:auto;height:auto;width:auto;max-height:100%;max-width:100%;" src="https://www.schaakengo.nl/images/productimages/big/goban-13x13-licht-2-.jpg">
    </img>
    <p>This paragraph should be visible, together with the image and the title.</p>
  </div>
  <h2>This does not have to fit vertically in the page</h2>
  <p>This works in Firefox but not Chrome. In Chrome, if I make the browser window very wide, the picture will take the full width, and become taller than the screen. In Firefox, the paragraph below the picture remains visible, which is what I want to obtain.
    How can I make it work in Chrome?</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for reading my question. I edited it with more details.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it will work with an image tag, but you can apply it as a background-image to a DIV and use `background-size: contain;` (to make sure the *whole*  image is always displayed without anything being cut off) and `flex-grow: 1;` (to allow the empty container to gain height) on it:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.outer_div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

.img_container {
  background: url(https://www.schaakengo.nl/images/productimages/big/goban-13x13-licht-2-.jpg) center center no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer_div">
  <h1>Title of the page that works in Firefox but not Chrome</h1>
  <div class="img_container"></div>
  <p>This paragraph should be visible, together with the image and the title.</p>
</div>
<h2>This does not have to fit vertically in the page</h2>
<p>This works in Firefox but not Chrome. In Chrome, if I make the browser window very wide, the picture will take the full width, and become taller than the screen. In Firefox, the paragraph below the picture remains visible, which is what I want to obtain.
  How can I make it work in Chrome?</p>
```

Comment: Thanks. I had managed to obtained a similar behavior by wrapping the img in a div. But it is different from what I want: your outer_div has a height instead of a max-height. So, with your solution, there will be plenty of white space before and after the picture if it does not fill the height of the page. My solution in Firefox does not have this white space.